# Using macro Concatenation of Multiple Columns on several line

Tags: excel, vba

I have columns (range A:C) with the following display

```
A             B           C            
Project 1   Article 1 Quantity 1
           Article 2  Quantity 2
           Article 3  Quantity 3
Project 2  Article 4  Quantity 4
           Article 5  Quantity 5
```

I tried using the Concatenate function, but each project doesn't have the same number of Article. The file has over 13000 lines so it will take a long time if i took each project one by one.
I know I can use VBA but i didn't find a solution on the internet

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Project 1 | Article 1 | Quantity 1 |
|  | Article 2 | Quantity 2 |
|  | Article 3 | Quantity 3 |
| Project 2 | Article 4 | Quantity 4 |
|  | Article 5 | Quantity 5 |

And I need to have:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Project 1 | Article 1 / Quantity 1 // Article 2 / Quantity 2 // Article 3 / Quantity 3 |
| Project 2 | Article 4 / Quantity 4 // Article 5 / Quantity 5 |

Comment: look into power query

Comment: The problem with Power query is that there is the "null" value in column A for Article 3, 5 and so on in the file

Comment: You can use Transform -> Fill down - that's what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you. Feel free to modify the logic to suit your needs.

```
Sub Macro()
Dim lngRow As Long
    For lngRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Range("A" & lngRow) = "" Then
        Range("B" & lngRow - 1) = Range("B" & lngRow - 1) & "|" & Range("B" & lngRow)
        Range("C" & lngRow - 1) = Range("C" & lngRow - 1) & "|" & Range("C" & lngRow)
        Range("B" & lngRow - 1) = Range("B" & lngRow - 1) & "|" & Range("C" & lngRow - 1)
        Range("B" & lngRow - 1).Offset(0, 1).Delete
        Rows(lngRow).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    Next
    Columns("C:C").Delete
End Sub
```

After:

[image]